# How to email a link to the current page using a bookmarklet without overwriting the content of the tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a Chrome JavaScript bookmarklet that will open my email handler to compose an email with the body containing a link to the current page and the subject being the title of the page. I found [this guidance](http://www.freeemailtutorials.com/webBrowsingAndEmail/emailUrlFromGoogleChrome.htm), which suggested using the following code in a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:document.location="mailto:?subject="+document.title+"&body="+escape(document.location);
```

This works, but has an annoying behavior of also replacing the content of the current tab with the literal `mailto` link location:

[image: Chrome window showing literal mailto link]

How can I modify the JavaScript so that the bookmarklet mails the link, but preserves the original page content in the browser?

I tried:

1. Adding `return false` at the end of the JavaScript. That prevented anything from happening (even generating the email).
2. Adding `location.reload()` after the semicolon as in:

   ```
   javascript:document.location="mailto:?subject="+document.title+"&body="+escape(document.location); location.reload();
   ```

   That reloaded the page, but did not generate the email.
3. Adding `location.reload()` before the semicolon as in

   ```
   javascript:document.location="mailto:?subject="+document.title+"&body="+escape(document.location) location.reload();
   ```

   That did nothing (didn't reload the page or generate the email).

I'd rather not use an extension for this because:

1. I find it easier to show / hide bookmarks than dealing with showing / hiding extension icons when I need them / don't need them.
2. I don't want to deal with activating, allowing in incognito, and browser version compatibility issues with extensions.

Comment: in 2019, it's probably far more sensible to write a webextension instead of a bookmarklet, given how much CORS and CSP have nerfed bookmarklets from even executed. Especially now that there are tools like [web-ext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-ext) that make the debugging and packing-up part super simple.

Comment: A bookmarklet is the better (only?) solution for Windows Chrome users whose browsers are managed by their organization and cannot install web extensions. It's 2020 and Google really needs to add a Share button to the File menu on desktop Chrome like they have on mobile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You can use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

The obvious solution to not overwrite the current page location is to use `window.open()`.

```
javascript:void(window.open("mailto:?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(document.title) + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(document.location)));
```

However, that creates a blank tab that will need to be closed, and will often encounter problems with popup blocking. Under some conditions, this tab can be closed programmatically, but that's going to depend on your browser, some browser settings, popup blocker extensions, etc.

#### Cleaner: use an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

For this use, it's just as effective, and less prone to problems, to use an `<iframe>`. The following bookmarklet adds an `<iframe>` to the end of the `document.body` using [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). Adding the `<iframe>` to the document will cause the `mailto` URL to be evaluated by your browser. The browser will then tell your email program to open a send-email window for you to send the email.

```
javascript:(function(){var now=Date.now(); document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<iframe id="iframe-to-delete-' + now + '" src="mailto:?subject=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title.trim()) + '&body=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location) + '" style="display: none !important"></iframe>'); setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('iframe-to-delete-'+now).remove(), 3000);})()
```

Once the your email program opens the send-email dialog, the bookmarklet can remove the `<iframe>`, which should leave the page undisturbed.